# Androidに和暦を扱えるCalendarは存在しますか？

Tags: android

OracleのJDK6実装では、

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP"); // ja_JP_JP
```

のロケールを利用することで和暦を扱うことができますが、Androidでは`GregorianCalendar`が返却される、という実装の違いがあります。

これはAndroidには`JapaneseImperialCalendar`が存在しない、ということなんでしょうか？

---

**UPDATE:** Android N にて[ICU4J Android フレームワーク API](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/preview/features/icu4j-framework.html)が提供されました。

```
android.icu.util.Calendar calendar = new android.icu.util.JapaneseCalendar();
android.icu.text.DateFormat df = new android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat("Gy年M月d日", new android.icu.text.DateFormatSymbols(calendar, Locale.JAPANESE));
df.setCalendar(calendar);
Log.d("Calendar", df.format(new Date())); // 平成28年4月30日
```

Android標準で和暦を扱うことができるようになりました（ただし Android N 以降のみ）。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Androidには`JapaneseImperialCalendar`は存在しないようですね。

参考：[androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2でのJapaneseImperialCalendar検索結果](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/search?q=JapaneseImperialCalendar&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools)

Comment: ソースを検索してみますと、ICU4Jの`JapaneseCalendar`はあるのですよね。しかし`getInstance()`の実装では`GregorianCalendar`しか返さないので、SDKから取得することはできないということなんでしょうか。

Comment: [`JapaneseCalendar`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/external/icu/icu4c/source/i18n/japancal.h#56)はexternal/icu内部のC++クラスのようですね。一方の[`Calendar#getInstance(Locale)`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Calendar.java#975) 実装は`return new GregorianCalendar(locale);`1行ですから、SDKから直接`JapaneseCalendar`にアクセスする術はなさそうです。（localeを渡しているので、これ以降を追えば何か分かるかも？）

Comment: `prebuilts/misc/common/icu4j`に`icu4j.jar`というJava向けのインターフェースも持ってはいるので、内部的に利用しているはずなのです。ただOpenJDKの`Calendar#getInstance()`の実装と比較すると、和暦とタイ仏暦の扱いが端折られてるので、`Calendar`として取得することは無理そうですね。

Answer (score 2):

すでに回答している方がいらっしゃいますがAndroidでは `JapaneseImperialCalendar` が使えません。

IBMが公開しているICUというライブラリがあります。
[ICU - International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/)
このライブラリの `JapaneseCalendar` を使えば和暦を使うことができます。
[JapaneseCalendar (ICU4J 54.1)](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/JapaneseCalendar.html)

jarを置くか、Mavenを使って利用すればよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。AndroidStudioですと`compile 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:54.1.1'`が楽です。しかし和暦のためだけにicu4j全体をアプリ内に持たせるのは微妙と考えていました。`Locale`クラスのドキュメントを読む限りでは、Android5.0ではICU 53をサポートしているとのことなので、もともとプライベートなインターフェースである`JapaneseImperialCalendar`はないにしても、その代替の実装がSDK内にあるのでは？と考えたのですが…。